# В чем может быть причина того,что проект на Xamarin компилируется очень долго в VS2015?

Tags: c#, xamarin

В чем может быть причина того,что проект на Xamarin при компиляции зависает и пишет,что кампилит,но это все происходит бесконечно, в VS2015,хотя в предыдущие разы компиляции компилировался быстро,а код не менялся?

Comment: бывает такое при смене рабочих веток git. отчищайте проект, удаляйте папки obj и bin, перезагружайте VS. удалите папку с пакетами nuget для проекта. посмотрите что получиться. Андройд проекты этим часто грешат

Comment: Ты не пишешь под какую платформу у тебя долго компилится.

Comment: я компилировал  под  андроид

Comment: @Nikita ну в принципе, что я и писал. Решение подошло?

Comment: @Dev да,подошло